# How to make a Web API Post Method trigger in a Html Form submit?

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, postman, webmethod, html-post

Currently I have a Web API Controller with a Post Method `[form body]` which does a post using PostMan to the Database.

Now the only thing I want to do is have that post method in the Web API work when a Html `form='post'` is submitted then let it post to the database. But How to make this happen?

Comment: I believe there is some basic understanding of HTML form posts to work though. A good, if a little old, Microsoft article has all of the steps needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1 Otherwise it would be helpful if you could post your Controller and HTML form to get a specific answer,

Comment: Yes this was the article i was looking at as reference for help. it has not completely helped out all the way, should I post what I have so far maybe it will give you a better idea at what i am trying to accomplish @tlbignerd

Comment: Formatting for readability.

Comment: oh Thank you @Nic3500 you are so nice for giving me a '-1' even tho i tried my best and when I found the answer I posted it. Thank you!

Comment: I hadn't; realized you were trying to do the ajax post of the values, when you mentioned using the form post. Your answer does what you're looking for, so I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @tlbignerd Thank you sir! and your link really helped out on this.

Comment: The `-1` is based on the question by itself.  If you read [ask] and [mcve] you will see that the question in itself barely fits within the context of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Everyone I was able to answer my own question, just for future viewers here's what I did

Html form with ajax:

```
<form method="post" action="Api/Values/Complex" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <select id="thisSelect">
            <option value="sp18br"> sp18br</option>
            <option value="sp18cl"> sp18cl</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />




    </form>

    <script>
        $("form").on("submit", function () {
            var post = $.post("api/values/complex", { "": $("#thisSelect").val() });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

ValuesController.cs:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Complex")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            if (value == "sp18br")
            {
                string cadena = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\azib\\Desktop\\dfb; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; User ID = Admin; Password =";
                string select = "Select * from sp18br ";
                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cadena);
                OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(select, con);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
                con.Open();


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();


                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    con1.Open();

                    foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertLeafPickup", con1);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Insert stored procedure

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dr1["PCOMBINED"]);
                        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeasonType", dr1["PSSSTREET"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextPickupdate", dr1["ZST"]);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    con.Close();
                    con1.Close();
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ok");
            }
            if (value == "sp18cl")
            {

                string cadena1 = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\azib\\Desktop\\dfb; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; User ID = Admin; Password =";
                string select1 = "Select * from sp18cl ";
                DataSet myDataSet1 = new DataSet();
                OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(cadena1);
                OleDbCommand myAccessCommand1 = new OleDbCommand(select1, con2);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand1);
                con2.Open();


                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                myDataAdapter1.Fill(dt1);
                con2.Close();


                string cs1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(cs1))
                {
                    con3.Open();

                    foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertLeafPickup", con3);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Insert stored procedure

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dr1["PCOMBINED"]);
                        //  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeasonType", dr1["PSSSTREET"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextPickupdate", dr1["ZST"]);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    con2.Close();
                    con3.Close();
                }


            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ok");
        }
```